# Issue with Web.xml for Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi I have been trying to map my controller with my jsp but however it is giving an error and displaying an old URL. I have tried cleaning project several times and changed my web.xml also.

below is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Sphibernate</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher </servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Below is my Controller class :

```
package com.lnt.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.lnt.services.AuthenticateServices;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping("Login.htm")
public class LoginController {

    //@Autowired
     AuthenticateServices authenticateService = new AuthenticateServices();

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processCredentials(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)

    {
        String userName =req.getParameter("userName") ;
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        System.out.println("into login controller");
        String message = "Invalid credentials";
        List<String> userdetails = new ArrayList<String>();
        userdetails = authenticateService.verifyUserNameAndPassword(userName, password);
        if((userdetails.get(0))!= userName && (userdetails.get(1))!= password )
            {
            message = "welcome" + userName ;
        }
        return new ModelAndView("results", "message", message) ;
    }



    }
```

Here is my JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Login.htm" method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "userName" id = "userName">
<input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

While calling my action through jsp i am getting an error :

type Status report

message /Login.spring

description The requested resource (/Login.spring) is not available.

However there is no url mapping as ".spring" in either jsp or controller or web.xml

@onepotato

here is my application context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSourceBean" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/springmvc"></property>
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="root"></property>        
    </bean> 
     <bean id="sessionFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceBean"></property>
       <!--<property name="mappingResources">
            <value>com.lnt.Pojo/Login.hbm.xml</value>                   
        </property>-->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
              <props>
                  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                  <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
              </props>
         </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="hibernateTemplateBean" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryBean"></property>
    </bean>
    <!--  <bean id="AuthenticateServiceBean" class="com.lnt.services.AuthenticateServices">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplateBean"></property>
    </bean> -->

</beans>
```

Below is my MVC Dispatcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.lnt.controller"></context:component-scan>

    <bean id = "viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
    <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
    <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>

    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Comment: Where is your application and web application context configuration? Where did you integrate it to your web app?

Comment: Given above..please check

Comment: How do you integrate those configs in your web app? Your application context should be passed as parameter to ContextLoaderListener which will create the DI and the web application context should be passed as param to your DispatcherServlet

Comment: if your welcome fine is Jsp then why u have put your url-pattern .htm???

Comment: did u restart your server?coz after doing changes in ur web.xml u need to restart the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to put "/Login" and NOT ".html" in Request mapping. This should work, if it it doesn't then try putting the Request mapping annotation above the method and not the class.

Comment: i agree i am clear with the logic but point is why is it giving mapping of old URL "login.spring" which is not existing in any of my xml

Comment: You must be using Eclipse right ?? Eclipse does behave wierd sometimes, try deleting the Server and deleting the .metadata and classes folder of your Project in your workspace. and then try importing the project in  a new workspace I've faced problems like this before.

Comment: No, he wants .htm (actually .html would be better) in the request mapping as he has his dispatcher servlet mapped to the url pattern "*.htm".  Your view resolver prefix is a bit odd, as you really want to put the .jsp files somewhere under /WEB-INF, ie, /WEB-INF/jsp/

Comment: In that case just add  
   <property name="suffix">
   <value>.html</value>
   </property>
But don't put a .html in @RequestMapping .. In Request mapping just put "/Login"

Answer (score 0):

1.Check Whether the control comes to the controller by printing some values in the console from the controller.If it prints then there is no problem with the request mapping.

2.Ensure the path to the jsp provided under the viewResolver bean matches with the path of the jsp file on the server.

3.If the controller does not reach the controller then try changing the @RequestMapping from "Login.htm" to "/Login.htm" because the browser I believe usually appends "/" before submitting a form.

If I have the same problem I would solve it the above way. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:Spring/servlet-context.xml,
    classpath:Spring/security-context.xml       
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```